# Using if statement in lists python

Tags: python, list, if-statement

```
shopping = [
    'Garlic',
    'Califlower',
    'Peppper',
    'Slat',
    'Oil',
    'Beer',
    'Toilet Paper',
    'Pizza'
]

for item in shopping:
    print(item)
    if item != 'Mashrum':
        print('we missed Mashrum!')
```

I want to get one print statement if this condition is false, instead of getting every time when it's looping?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!, please, could you format your question and expected output? Code should have backticks, click on help to see some examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
shopping = [ 'Garlic', 'Califlower', 'Peppper', 'Slat', 'Oil', 'Beer', 'Toilet Paper', 'Pizza' ]
if 'Mashrum' not in shopping:
    print('we missed Mashrum!')
```

That will print you the print statement if 'Mashrum' not in the shopping list.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `any`:

```
x = any('Mashrum' == item for item in shopping)
if not x:
    print("Mashrum was missed")
```

Comment: I didn't get any output when I run it!!

Comment: that means you dont have "Mashrum" in your shopping list :)